# warning C4100: '$initVBases' : unreferenced formal parameter

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

A strange warning on Visual Studio 2013 that I don't understand. Here is a code sample:

```
class Base : General::Updatable, virtual public sf::Drawable, public Input::Handler
{
public:
    Base();
    Base(sf::Vector2i size, sf::Vector2i position);
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
    virtual void Update(sf::Time delta) override = 0;
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const override = 0;

protected:
    sf::Vector2i size;
    sf::Vector2i position;
};

General::Interface::Window::Base::Base(sf::Vector2i size, sf::Vector2i position)
: size(size)
, position(position)
{
}

General::Interface::Window::Base::Base()
: Base(sf::Vector2i(0, 0), sf::Vector2i(0, 0)) // **** warning C4100
{
}
```

> warning C4100: '$initVBases' : unreferenced formal parameter on the
>   indicated line.

Comment: There seems to be a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/774986/codename-milan-delegating-constructors-causes-warning-c4100-initvbases-unreferenced-formal-parameter-w4-when-derived-class-uses-virtual-inheritance) for this. Unfortunately, it is deferred so it seems this will be yet another spurious VS warning that won't vanish anytime soon.